# PHP function not recognizing array from required file when using parameter "global"

Tags: php, function, require

How can it be that the below works:

```
require('../PHP/array.txt');
function printarray($includedarray){
print_r($includedarray);
}
printarray($includedarray);
```

but the following doesn't:

```
require('../PHP/array.txt');
function printarray(){
global $includedarray;
print_r($includedarray);
}
printarray();
```

when indeed there is an array called "$includedarray" in the required file. I'm not getting an error message or anything on the second example. How is this possible... I don't even know where to begin looking for an answer on this one.

Note that the php file which requires `array.txt` is previously included from another PHP file. But surely this cannot be an issue as the first example does work.

Comment: Why are you using global anyway? Passing variables is a better approach. And why are you requiring a txt file  and render it as php code?

Comment: Well, thats beside the point.

Comment: It just happens to be. That doesn't affect the code though. For the example I could change it to .php with no difference in results.

Comment: What does the file array.txt look like? Is it only an array declaration?

Comment: @EL not sure what to make of the results. What should I be expecting?

Comment: Is your `$includedarray` in `array.txt` enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags?

Comment: @Matte search there for $includedarray, of course.